# Why is window.print giving duplicate pages?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to print a modal dialog in a React component. When the component that is under the modal takes up more than 1 page, the printing of the modal is duplicated for each page.

Since the div that I want to print is overlayed on other divs, I am using style-components library to set the @media print properties to only show the print target. In the page, I have the following:

```
const NoPrintBody = createGlobalStyle`
  @media print {
    html, body {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
`;
```

and the render contains the <NoPrintBody /> element.

Then, in the modal, I have:

```
const ReportContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;

  @media print {
    visibility: visible;
  }
`;
```

and here the modal is surrounded by the <ReportContainer> element. I've tried to set the height of the underlying content to 0px, but that did not have any affect.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue. My print media query sets the target div's position to fixed and width and height to 100vw/h to just cover the entire page. But now I get two pages in print view when window.print() is called.

Comment: We ended up doing it without using a modal (by navigating to a new route (using React).

Comment: Ah.. I also figured this out. I couldn't find my comment so I could edit it. I was getting duplicates when using `display: fixed` in the print media query.

Answer (score 0):

Is your global style getting updated correctly? You should be able to find that css somewhere on the page.

I don't think NoPrintBody will work since it is targeting the html tag - even your modal should be a child of that.

Have you tried it without `@media print` ? If you can get it to look how you want it to in the browser you should be able to add it back to get it to print how you want

Comment: I'm sure the global style is updating correctly because, without it, other things like the underlying page and the menus show up on the print.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same issue in a vue.js app.
I think the problem is because an SPA like its name say's is just a single page application. So as long as there is a component with content that can't be contained in a single page the print function will include those pages even if you aren't trying to print that component.

I fixed it by adding this to my global css file.

```
@media print {

  html, body {
    height:100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
  }

}
```

This should force the print function to only pick one page.

Comment: this seems like half an answer, if the content is more than one page, it gets cut, which is not something we'd want to achieve, I'm still working on finding the proper solution.